# Validation rule to prevent account name change on opportunity

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule

I am trying to write a validation rule to prevent users from changing Account name on the Opportunity once a value is present in a custom text field on that Opportunity.

If I use `ISCHANGED(Account.Name)` I get

> "Error: The ISCHANGED function cannot reference the Account.Name
>   field."

and when I try with `ISCHANGED(Account)` I get

> " Error: Field Account does not exist. Check spelling."

Can you please help me with the formula?

Comment: Try ISCHANGED(AccountId)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to restrict changes to Account field only if the field already has a value, then you can use something like this

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(AccountId)),
  ISCHANGED(AccountId)
)
```

this will check if the Account field has changed and if it already has a value.